# Force to store getter result in variable if it is used inside of the loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

Consider following class

```
class Smth {
  get functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName() {
    // Some heavy calculations are here
    return obj => obj; // Actually uses some vars from closure calculated above
  }
}
```

I want to have a tslint error on any access to getter inside of the loop.

I. e. any of following lines should be considered bad:

```
for (var x of a) smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
a.forEach(x => smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
a.map(x => smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
```

and any of the following - good:

```
var functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName = smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName;
for (var x of a) functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
a.forEach(x => functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
a.map(x => functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
```

And this one is good too as the argument is calculated only once:

```
a.map(smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName)
```

And call ouside of the loop should be valid:

```
var x = smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(mySingleObject)
```

**What tslint rule can be configuref to do such thing?**

Note that name check and dot in access are enough, I don' need to ensure that function belongs to some concrete class.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do. However, I feel like it is the wrong approach and will lead to future bugs. You are using a getter that effectively takes input. I would reject this in a code review for that fact alone. Perhaps, you could consider caching the slow calculations. If you want a caching solution I can provide one otherwise I'd recommend you ask this directly on https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules/issues as I think you are more likely to get the answer there and faster. Or take a look at the src as they have many loop rules.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs, getter depends on the state of the class only. I can write some caching myself, but unfortunately it doesn't suite because of some other reasons. I thought there is some rule like that as there are some other loop-related rules.

Comment: this would throw an error based on your example code smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x)

Comment: @MichaelHobbs, what would throw?

Comment: in your example you define Smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName as a getter so trying to call it smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x) would never work. Unless getters work vastly different in TS vs JS.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs, but as getter returns function, that function is called. Isn't it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tggxk.png

Comment: @MichaelHobbs, I've made a rule.

Comment: No, see test
class A { get b() {return (x) => console.log(x)} }
var a = new A()
a.b(42) // throws error Uncaught TypeError: a.b is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196875/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-michael-hobbs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I've made corresponding rule ([demo on AstExplorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/37c73d77033fe5f4ffcd0b75bd12f96d/1b2de2c51ca373db9956dae8ada0f5afa2c4be97)):

```
import * as Lint from "tslint";
import * as ts from "typescript";

const arrayMethods = new Set(["find", "findIndex", "sort", "forEach", "filter", "flatMap", "map", "every", "some", "reduce", "reduceRight"]);

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
  public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[]  {
    return this.applyWithWalker(new DisallowGetterInsideOfTheLoopWalker(sourceFile, this.getOptions()));
  }
}

class DisallowGetterInsideOfTheLoopWalker extends Lint.RuleWalker {
  private loops = 0;
  private names: Set<string>;

  constructor(sourceFile, options) {
    super(sourceFile, options);
    this.loops = 0;
    this.names = new Set(["functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName"] /* options.ruleArguments */);
  }

  public visitCallExpression(node: ts.CallExpression) {
    var isLoop = node.expression.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.PropertyAccessExpression && arrayMethods.has(node.expression.name.text);

    this.loops += isLoop as any;
    super.visitPropertyAccessExpression(node);
    this.loops -= isLoop as any;
  }

  public visitPropertyAccessExpression(node: ts.PropertyAccessExpression) {
    if (this.loops && this.names.has(node.name.text) && (this.loops > 1 || node.parent.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.CallExpression && node.parent.expression === node)) {
      this.addFailure(this.createFailure(node.name.pos, node.name.end - node.name.pos, `Do not get ${node.name.text} inside of the loop`));
    }

    super.visitPropertyAccessExpression(node);
  }

  public visitForOfStatement(node: ts.ForOfStatement) {
    this.loops += 2;
    super.visitForOfStatement(node);
    this.loops -= 2;
  }

  public visitForInStatement(node: ts.ForInStatement) {
    this.loops += 2;
    super.visitForInStatement(node);
    this.loops -= 2;
  }

  public visitForStatement(node: ts.ForStatement) {
    this.loops += 2;
    super.visitForStatement(node);
    this.loops -= 2;
  }

  public visitDoStatement(node: ts.DoStatement) {
    this.loops += 2;
    super.visitDoStatement(node);
    this.loops -= 2;
  }

  public visitWhileStatement(node: ts.WhileStatement) {
    this.loops += 2;
    super.visitWhileStatement(node);
    this.loops -= 2;
  }
}
```

Invalid cases:

```
for (var x of a) smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
for (var x in obj) smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
a.forEach(x => smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
a.map(x => smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
a.map(x => smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName<T>(x))
for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
do smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x); while (0)
while (1) smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
while (1) (smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName)(x);
while (1) var f = smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName;
while (1) (smth as any).functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName;
```

Valid cases:

```
var functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName = smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName;

for (var x of a) functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
for (var x in obj) functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
a.forEach(x => functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
a.map(x => functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x))
for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
do functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x); while (0)
while (1) functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(x);
while (1) (functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName)(x);

a.map(smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName)
smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName(mySingleObject)
```

Unwanted valid cases:

```
a.map(x => (smth.functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName)(x))
```