# Use custom `tslint` rule without compilation from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I've [made my own tslint rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57150807/4928642), saved into `tslint-rules/disallowGetterInsideOfTheLoopRule.ts` and added it into tslint config:

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:latest",
        "tslint-react"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "disallow-getter-inside-of-the-loop": [true, "functionWithSomeVeryUniqueName"]
    },
    "rulesDirectory": [
        "./tslint-rules"
    ]
}
```

But it works only if I compile it to JavaScript and update import/export statements in compiled file:

```
var Lint = require("tslint");
var ts = require("typescript");
const arrayMethods = new Set(["find", "findIndex", "sort", "forEach", "filter", "flatMap", "map", "every", "some", "reduce", "reduceRight"]);
module.exports.Rule = class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
    apply(sourceFile) {
```

**How can I use my rule in TypeScript without compilation?**

To run linting I'm currently using `npm run lint` with following script:

```
"lint": "tslint --config tslint.json --project tsconfig.json \"src/**/*.ts{,x}\"",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now configured compilation without need to do manual updates:

```
"compile-lint-rules": "for %f in (./tslint-rules/*.ts) do tsc \"./tslint-rules/%f\" --lib es2018 --skipLibCheck --outDir ./tslint-rules/bin",
"lint": "npm run compile-lint-rules && tslint --config tslint.json --project tsconfig.json \"src/**/*.ts{,x}\"",
```

Of course tslint config changed to

```
"rulesDirectory": [
    "./tslint-rules/bin"
]
```